# clear EditText when Enter is pressed

Tags: android

I want to clear an EditText when i click a button or press Enter. It works fine with the button, but when pressing Enter, it clears both the EditText and TextView.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        textViewEcho.setText(editTextInput.getText().toString());
        editTextInput.setText("");
    }

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == 66) {
        textViewEcho.setText(editTextInput.getText().toString());
        editTextInput.setText("");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Update: i found out that onKey is called twice, that's why the TextView's content is cleared, but can't figure out why onKey is called twice, is this a bug in Android?!!!!!

i tried onKeyUp instead, it does work.

Comment: Try by assigning the **editTextInput.getText().toString())** to a String variable before editTextInput.setText("") and later assign that String value to textViewEcho.

Comment: onKey is called twice because once its for KEY_DOWN and once for KEY_UP event.

Answer (score 1):

try this, need to return true.

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == 66) {
        String txt = editTextInput.getText().toString();
        textViewEcho.setText(txt);
        editTextInput.setText("");
        return true; // return the true from here
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you Pratik, return true made the EditText field stable (it used to move before using it), but still, the textView gets cleared, when I press Enter. by the way, the result is the same with or without assigning editTextInput.getText().toString() to a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
//write the code what ever u want when u press enter                {
edittext.setText("");

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```